# Resetting setTimeout() within a class definition

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, settimeout

In typescript, I am trying to reset a timer based on a click function. I have looked at the solutions around clearTimeout, but they don't seem to fit the situation where I have the setTimeout() defined in a class.

```
import { ModalAction } from "./modalScript.js";
export class Timer {
  private interval: number;
  constructor(interval: number) {
    this.interval = interval;
  }

  startTimer() {
    console.log("startedTimer");
    setTimeout(function () {
      let mod = new ModalAction();
      mod.renderModal();
    }, this.interval);
  }
  resetTimer() {
    clearTimeout();
  }
}
```

In my external class, I am creating a new Timer class passing in an interval.  I would like to be able to call myTimerObject.clearTimeout() from my external class.  clearTimeout expects a number. i have tried setting startTimeout() to a variable, but when calling it in clearTimout(), it does not read as a number.

---

Implemented the suggestion and it works, with a couple of changes and a new question.
I had to declare the variable in the constructor, otherwise typescript complained of not initialized. So now, when I create the new object from my external class, I have to pass in a number argument. I randomly pass in the number 1. seems a little unclean, but it functions. Any improvements??

```
import { ModalAction } from "./modalScript.js";
export class Timer {
  private interval: number;
  **private handler: number;**
  constructor(interval: number, **handler: number**) {
    this.interval = interval;
    **this.handler = handler;**
  }

  startTimer() {
    console.log("starting timer");
    this.handler = setTimeout(function () {
      let mod = new ModalAction();
      mod.renderModal();
    }, this.interval);
  }
  resetTimer() {
    console.log("timer reset");
    clearTimeout(this.handler);
    this.startTimer();
  }
}
```

Is built with myObject = new Timer(10000, 1);

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to accomplish? Do you want to effectively cancel the timeout before the interval is reached and the callback is performed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to cancel setTimeout from this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125967/how-to-cancel-settimeout-from-this)

Answer (score 1):

You can fix your code by assigning the setTimeout result to a variable and use it in clearTimeout.

```
import { ModalAction } from "./modalScript.js";
export class Timer {
  private interval: number;
  private handler?: ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>;
  constructor(interval: number) {
    this.interval = interval;
  }

  startTimer() {
    console.log("startedTimer");
    this.handler = setTimeout(function () {
      let mod = new ModalAction();
      mod.renderModal();
    }, this.interval);
  }

  resetTimer() {
    clearTimeout(this.handler);
  }
}
```

alternatively you can use `number` as the return type of setTimeout.

Comment: I edited my question to reflect your suggestions. Any feedback is appreciated on improving or cleaning up. Otherwise it functions as needed.

Comment: Please don't answer the question in the question itself, if you have a better answer please add it as an answer.

Comment: The reason why typescript is complaining is that you forgot to make the number nullable like the example in this answer, the `?` operator before `:type`.

Comment: sorry, the comment section doesn't allow me to paste code. Editing my question was the only way to illustrate my follow up questions. I didnt consider it an answer. Everything works, i appreciate the information, it was very helpful.